# General use of Linked List

Tags: java, linked-list

I know you can create your own Linked List class or import one with java.util.
Like so :

```
import java.util.*;  

LinkedList<String> ll=new LinkedList<String>();
```

and then do some stuff to the list with the already existing methods, like add, get, set...
But you can also create your own Linked List liked that :

```
class LinkedList {
Node head; // head of list


class Node {
    int data;
    Node next;

    Node(int d) { data = d; }
}
}
```

But if you're doing it like that you need to create all of the methods.
My question is pretty simple, should I use method 1 or 2 ? And if both are fine when would it be better to use one over another.

Comment: Honestly, unless you know why you are specifically using `LinkedList`, it is usually better to just use `ArrayList`.  Also why would you create your own implementation of `LinkedList` to begin with?

Comment: It’s better to use the already-implemented one unless you want to write your own.

Comment: You should use the existing, standard `LinkedList`, because it has been tested and used millions of times by many thousands of programmers and works fine. You should only write your own if it's specifically required, for a school assignment, for example.

Comment: @Nexevis To learn how to write a linked list implementation.

Comment: @Dave Newton Well then he wouldn't be asking if he should just use `LinkedList` instead of writing his own if thats his intended purpose?

Comment: @Nexevis You asked why, I answered ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Nexevis - because Java's implementation of linked list has issues, which are explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67602528/67606719#67606719) .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need a general-purpose `List`, use `java.util.LinkedList`. It's a standard class, mature, well-tested, well-understood by almost any Java dev... and, ofc, it's concise, because you don't have to implement it.

Actually, don't use it: use `java.util.ArrayList` or `java.util.ArrayDeque`, they out-perform `LinkedList` in almost all circumstances. See [When to use LinkedList over ArrayList in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/322715/when-to-use-linkedlist-over-arraylist-in-java)

If you *really* need something more specialized, implement your own, but only if you *really, really* need it.

Only make your class implement `java.util.List` if you actually need it to.

A good starting point to avoid having to implement "everything" in the interface is to extend [`java.util.AbstractList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/AbstractList.html): this only requires you to provide an implementation of `get(int)`, `size()` and, if you want the list to be modifiable, `set(int, E)` (you may well want to override others to get better performance for a linked list).

Answer (score 2):

Don't reinvent the wheel unless you need something extremely specific that the existing wheel doesn't provide.

Also, might be worth mentioning that linked lists have poor performance characteristics since the memory they occupy isn't continuous, causing the multiple reads from main memory ([link](https://dzone.com/articles/performance-of-array-vs-linked-list-on-modern-comp)).

Comment: That's an insightful article to read. I will have to check myself if it's true in java as the author explained. Thank you for sharing this.